# vscode remote-ssh cannot connect to server

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vagrant

I've been developing locally by connecting to Vagrant (vartualbox) with vscode remote-ssh.
But when I restarted vagrant and tried to connect remotely
I get "Time limit reached" and "Could not fetch remote environment" and I can't connect.
I can connect with "vagrant ssh" and "ssh command", but I can't.

error log

```
[2020-09-11 02:37:51.947] [renderer3] [error] [remote-connection] The time limit has been reached for a connection. Error:
[2020-09-11 02:37:51.947] [renderer3] [error] Error: Time limit reached
    at file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1879:292
[2020-09-11 02:37:51.947] [renderer3] [error] [remote-connection] An error occurred in the very first connect attempt, it will be treated as a permanent error! Error:
[2020-09-11 02:37:51.947] [renderer3] [error] Error: Time limit reached
    at file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1879:292
[2020-09-11 02:37:52.061] [renderer3] [error] Time limit reached: Error: Time limit reached
    at file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1879:292
[2020-09-11 02:37:52.221] [renderer3] [error] [remote-connection] The time limit has been reached for a connection. Error:
[2020-09-11 02:37:52.222] [renderer3] [error] Error: Time limit reached
    at file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1879:292
[2020-09-11 02:37:52.222] [renderer3] [error] [remote-connection] An error occurred in the very first connect attempt, it will be treated as a permanent error! Error:
[2020-09-11 02:37:52.222] [renderer3] [error] Error: Time limit reached
    at file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1879:292
[2020-09-11 02:37:52.258] [renderer3] [error] Could not fetch remote environment: Error: Could not fetch remote environment
    at d.start (file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:5022:70)
    at async k.createProcess (file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:5039:827)
```

```
[02:37:21.902] Starting forwarding server. localPort 55555 -> socksPort 54444 -> remotePort 43333
[02:37:21.902] Forwarding server listening on 55555
[02:37:21.902] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[02:37:21.904] [Forwarding server 55555] Got connection 0
[02:37:21.905] Tunneled remote port 43333 to local port 55555
[02:37:21.905] Resolved "ssh-remote+ruby02" to "127.0.0.1:55555"
[02:37:21.921] ------

[02:37:21.948] [Forwarding server 55555] Got connection 1
[02:37:21.949] [Forwarding server 55555] Got connection 2
[02:38:55.872] Picking SSH host
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

1. Login to your remote machine
2. Get the PID of all vscode-server proccess running in your remote machine
3. Kill them
4. Try to login to your remote machine again via vscode ssh extension